# calling web-services using rhomobile

Tags: web-services, rhomobile

I am developing a project on RHO mobile where I need to call web-services to login into the application and registered user information stored in the server. Can anyone tell me how to do  it with RHO mobile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This topic could help:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.1.0/guide/web_services

Also, you could use directly the Net::HTTP Ruby methods